# error using ether libary in react js to get balance of wallet

Tags: reactjs, ethereum

Error using **ether** library in ReactJS to get balance of wallet. As I mention in the title. I'm getting a weird error when I try using the **ether** library I did do the NPM install, getting this error when checking the local host:

here is my error msg:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-gyp-build/node-gyp-build.js 1:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/gustavopayano/Desktop/navbar/node_modules/node-gyp-build'

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-gyp-build/node-gyp-build.js 2:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/gustavopayano/Desktop/navbar/node_modules/node-gyp-build'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/gustavopayano/Desktop/navbar/node_modules/node-gyp-build'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

here is my ReactJS component that implements a Metamask wallet connection code:

```js
import { React, useState } from "react";
import "./App";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import "./css/Metamask.css";

function Metamask() {
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
  const [defaultAccount, setDefaultAccount] = useState(null);
  const [userBalance, setUserBalance] = useState(null);

  const ethers = require("ethers");

  const connectWallet = () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.ethereum
        .request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
        .then((result) => {
          accountChanged(result[0]);
        });
    } else {
      setErrorMessage("Install MetaMask Please!");
    }
  };

  const accountChanged = (accountName) => {
    setDefaultAccount(accountName);
    getUserBalance(accountName);
  };

  const getUserBalance = (accountAddress) => {
    window.ethereum
      .request({
        method: "eth_getBalance",
        params: [String(accountAddress), "latest"],
      })
      .then((balance) => {
        setUserBalance(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance));
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="metamask">
      <Navbar />
      <h1>Metamask Wallet Connection</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" onClick={connectWallet}>
        {" "}
        Connect Metamask
      </button>
      <h3>Address: {defaultAccount}</h3>
      <h3>Balance: {userBalance}</h3>

      {errorMessage}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Metamask;
```

The `connectWallet()` function checks if the Metamask extension is installed in the user's browser. If it is installed, it sends a request to the Metamask extension to connect the user's wallet. If the connection is successful, the `accountChanged()` function is called, which sets the `defaultAccount` state and calls `getUserBalance()` to get the user's wallet balance. If the Metamask extension is not installed, the `setErrorMessage()` function is called to display an error message to the user.

Comment: any time a module wants to require fs you can assume it's node only and not compatible with frontend js like react

Comment: oh, what would you do in this situation?

Comment: you have to either figure out which package is a backend package and remove it or if you're sure they're all ok use webpack polyfills

Answer (score 0):

1.Add these to your `devDependencies` and run `yarn/npm install` .

```
"devDependencies": {
"assert": "^2.0.0",
"buffer": "^6.0.3",
"crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
"https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
"os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
"process": "^0.11.10",
"react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
"stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
"stream-http": "^3.2.0",
"url": "^0.11.0"}
```

2.run `npm install (or yarn)` to ensure all deps are downloaded.

3.Change your scripts in `package.json` to run with react-app-rewired:

```
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
"test": "react-app-rewired test",
"eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
```

4.Create a `config.overrides.js` in your root folder and copy and paste the following into it:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(config) {
  const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
  Object.assign(fallback, {
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    assert: require.resolve("assert"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    os: require.resolve("os-browserify"),
    url: require.resolve("url"),
  });
  config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
  config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
  ]);
  return config;
};
```

5.if there is any other errors , make sure to resolve it in `config.overrides.js` adding a fallback .